Turn text off in Hyperlink created in InDesign when exported to Adobe PDF
I've generated hyperlinks indesign, I automated them so that I didn't have to individually create them. I then made the text box opacity zero. When I export to a PDF the link works but it also shows the text highlighted. Is there a way to turn this off in Acrobat Pro so when I hover over it only shows the mouse cursor to lead to the URL? I'm trying to create this in an automated way in InDesign so I don't have to individually create a lot of URL's.


From what I understand, what you want is to create an interacting button to access the external URL. This should be a better solution than using invisible text to open the link when you hover over it.
However, if you cannot use buttons due to technical difficulties, you can go in the Properties pannel while selecting the URL and replace the visible text by some space.
